# Is mica used in electronic devices and/or PCBs?

Tags: capacitor, pcb

I am researching mica in the electronics and electrical sectors and I would like to know if mica is used on PCBs and if so, where and for what products?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not post a specific electronics **design** question but is rather an industrial survey.

Comment: Mica is used (or use to be) to make optical wave plates.  (a wave plate will change to polarization of the light beam.)

Comment: Mica is used in the surge protection industry to prevent a flash-over from one phase to another if an MOV exploded and forms hot plasma. Yes, you could call it a blast shield.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comments but I want to correct Chris because I am not conducting an industrial survey. I work at a public interest research institute and am tasked with writing a report about where mica, which is mined under horrific labour conditions, is used in the electronics industry. There is no analytical oversight of mica and I though this forum might help me understand whether mica capacitors or mica as insulation could be found on PCB. Any thoughts, references or comments that might help me with this research is much appreciated. All best, RBC

Answer (score 3):

Mica is used

- as electrically insulating material at high temperatures (e.g. between a transistor casing and heat sink; in toasters as supporting material holding the heating wire):
  [image: Mica insulation material]
  <sup>(Image from Wikimedia, Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license)</sup>
- in mica capacitors

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should mention what you have researched so far, as some answers may be repeating stuff you have come across already.

As far as I know (someone can correct me if I am wrong) it is mainly used in high precision capacitors. That is the only place I have heard it used.

You get silver mica capacitors, which have high precision, reliability and stability. I also believe they have good thermal properties. They cost quite a bit more than other types of capacitors, but will usually only go up to a couple of nanofarads, although do usually have higher voltage ratings than other types.

You would use them where you need low capacitance and high stability over time. They would mostly be used in RF circuits.

Hopefully this is a good starting point for you

Answer (score 0):

Mica capacitors are used in high stability reference capacitors.  They are used in small value RF capacitors.  They are found in much larger capacitors in the form of mica paper, small mica pieces bonded with epoxy or other adhesives.  The world’s supply of large, high quality mica plates was used up many decades ago.  Mica has good resistance to corona so it is used in high voltage applications.
[image]